# How to record the user voice in Objective-C for iPhone

Tags: ios, objective-c, playback, avaudiorecorder, voice-recording

I want to record the user voice and then play it back after some time.

Is there any way to do this in Objective-C for iPhone?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215180/record-and-play-audio-simultaneously/20212083#20212083

Answer (score 1):

Use AVAudioRecorder for doing this. For more help see this [tutorial.](http://www.mobileorchard.com/tutorial-detecting-when-a-user-blows-into-the-mic/)

Hope this helps.

Comment: @Zsolt check your proxy settings or firewall. This link loads fine for me.