# I want to record and play the audio with iphone but not through microphone ..?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I want to record the user's voice without using the headphone. I want to record it directly by iPhone and play it directly by speaker. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Didn't you just ask this same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978698/how-to-record-the-user-voice-in-objective-c-for-iphone

Answer (score 2):

To learn how to record audio from the microphone, take a look at the [Speak Here sample code](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/SpeakHere/index.html) Apple provides.

Answer (score 2):

If you mean you want to record and play without using the microphone and speakers on the headphone cords, then you can simply remove the headphone plug from the jack and the iPhone will revert to the microphone and speakers builtin to the body of the phone itself.

The easiest way to record and playback with the API is to use [AVAudioRecorder](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioRecorder_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008238-CH1-SW24) and [AVAudioPlayer](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioPlayerClassReference/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008067-CH1-SW11).

If this is not what you wanted you might want to flesh your question out a bit.

Comment: i what to record after removing the microphone from my app

Comment: The iPhone has a built-in microphone. As TechZen already said: The phone will fall back to it's built-in mic/speaker as soon as you remove the headphones.

Comment: Just to clarify, the control of the headset microphone versus the built in microphone is done in the hardware. You cannot pick with microphone/speaker set to use by software. If the headset is plugged in the hardware uses the headset and nothing in software can change that.

Comment: If you don't use headphones, there will be a whistle.