# Record and play audio Simultaneously

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-audio, audio-recording

Any one help to me to record and play audio Simultaneously in Iphone.

Comment: Send me more description. The recording should be done by mic? How precise have to be synchronization, etc. Perhaps you should check out apple sample code aurioTouch.

Comment: You can play and record simultaneously on iOS devices (except the 1st gen Touch) using either the Audio Unit RemoteIO or the Audio Queue API. These are lower level APIs where you have to handle the incoming buffers of outgoing and incoming PCM samples yourself. See Apple's aurioTouch sample app for example code.

Answer (score 9):

You can get a use from AVFoundation framework. It has AVAudioPlayer to play audio files and AVAudioRecorder to record.
You have to bear in mind that Recorder will record with the use of mic only.
So with the simultameously playing a audio file and recording it depends on how the mic will perceive the audio that is played.

Answer (score 2):

Please Check [aurioTouch](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/aurioTouch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007770) apple sample code for audio record-and-play simultaneously

You can also check [Recording Audio on an iPhone](http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Recording_Audio_on_an_iPhone_with_AVAudioRecorder_%28iOS_4%29)

Answer (score 0):

To record an play the audio files in iOS, you can use AVFoundation framework. Use below swift code to record and play the audios.
Remember that recorder will record the audio with the use of mic, so please test this code on device.

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

extension String {

       func stringByAppendingPathComponent(path: String) -> String {

       let nsSt = self as NSString
       return nsSt.stringByAppendingPathComponent(path)
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, AVAudioPlayerDelegate, AVAudioRecorderDelegate{

var audioPlayer : AVAudioPlayer!
var audioRecorder : AVAudioRecorder!

@IBOutlet var recordButton : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var playButton : UIButton!
@IBOutlet var stopButton : UIButton!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    self.recordButton.enabled = true
    self.playButton.enabled = false
    self.stopButton.enabled = false
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
}

//MARK: UIButton action methods

@IBAction func playButtonClicked(sender : AnyObject){

    let dispatchQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
    dispatch_async(dispatchQueue, {

        if let data = NSData(contentsOfFile: self.audioFilePath())
        {
            do{
                self.audioPlayer = try AVAudioPlayer(data: data)
                self.audioPlayer.delegate = self
                self.audioPlayer.prepareToPlay()
                self.audioPlayer.play()
            }
            catch{
                print("\(error)")
            }
        }
    });
}

@IBAction func stopButtonClicked(sender : AnyObject){

    if let player = self.audioPlayer{
        player.stop()
    }

    if let record = self.audioRecorder{

        record.stop()

        let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do{
            try session.setActive(false)
        }
        catch{
            print("\(error)")
        }
    }
}

@IBAction func recordButtonClicked(sender : AnyObject){

    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()

    do{
        try session.setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord)
        try session.setActive(true)
        session.requestRecordPermission({ (allowed : Bool) -> Void in

            if allowed {
                self.startRecording()
            }
            else{
                print("We don't have request permission for recording.")
            }
        })
    }
    catch{
        print("\(error)")
    }
}

func startRecording(){

    self.playButton.enabled = false
    self.recordButton.enabled = false
    self.stopButton.enabled = true

    do{

        let fileURL = NSURL(string: self.audioFilePath())!
        self.audioRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder(URL: fileURL, settings: self.audioRecorderSettings() as! [String : AnyObject])

        if let recorder = self.audioRecorder{
            recorder.delegate = self

            if recorder.record() && recorder.prepareToRecord(){
                print("Audio recording started successfully")
            }
        }
    }
    catch{
        print("\(error)")
    }
}

func audioFilePath() -> String{

    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory, NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask, true)[0]
    let filePath = path.stringByAppendingPathComponent("test.caf") as String

    return filePath
}

func audioRecorderSettings() -> NSDictionary{

    let settings = [AVFormatIDKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC)), AVSampleRateKey : NSNumber(float: Float(16000.0)), AVNumberOfChannelsKey : NSNumber(int: 1), AVEncoderAudioQualityKey : NSNumber(int: Int32(AVAudioQuality.Medium.rawValue))]

    return settings
}

//MARK: AVAudioPlayerDelegate methods

func audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying(player: AVAudioPlayer, successfully flag: Bool) {

    if flag == true{
        print("Player stops playing successfully")
    }
    else{
        print("Player interrupted")
    }

    self.recordButton.enabled = true
    self.playButton.enabled = false
    self.stopButton.enabled = false
}

//MARK: AVAudioRecorderDelegate methods

func audioRecorderDidFinishRecording(recorder: AVAudioRecorder, successfully flag: Bool) {

    if flag == true{
        print("Recording stops successfully")
    }
    else{
        print("Stopping recording failed")
    }

    self.playButton.enabled = true
    self.recordButton.enabled = false
    self.stopButton.enabled = false
}
}
```

I had tested this code on xCode 7.0 & iOS 9.

Comment: I want to record output audio(I mean live streaming audio or speaker audio)

Comment: in **iOS 12.4.1** this solution don't start record when the audio is playing in background (so when the app is not in foreground)