# Is there a way to record device audio on the iPhone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, core-audio

AVAudioRecorder allows the recording of external audio. However I wish to record the audio made by my application (through numerous AVAudioPlayers), is this possible on the iPhone?

Comment: possible duplicate [Record and play audio Simultaneously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215180/record-and-play-audio-simultaneously)

Comment: The applications allows the user to play sounds by pressing numerous buttons. I like to record the sounds the user makes with these buttons so they can play it back.

Comment: I need the same I you found please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to record the sounds your iOS app makes, you have to use a much lower lever API, such as Audio Unit RemoteIO, or Audio Queues with raw PCM audio samples.

Comment: Can you provide a link to where I can learn more about this technique?

Comment: Google is your friend here.   for remoteIO there is a very simple tone generator example from ' cocoa with love ' blog.  for audio queues there is a nice simple tutorial on the ' trails in the sand ' blog, but you will have to dig for it a bit.