# Simultaneous play and record iOS 9

Tags: ios, audio, avfoundation

I am trying to set up a simple player and recorder for iOS. I want to be able to play a file with noise sound through the headphone jack and listen to it simultaneously with the iPhone's built-in microphone. Am I able to do that with AVFoundation and Swift? I found some answers to simmilar questions mentioning RemoteIO framework but I can't seem to understand how this one works.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4215180/record-and-play-audio-simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Yes, simultaneous audio record and play can be done in Swift 2.x on iOS 9 devices.  Here's one Gist: https://gist.github.com/hotpaw2/630a466cc830e3d129b9 for play.  You can add an AUInputHandler and RenderBlock for mic input samples.