# iPhone: Access voice memos programmatically

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, avaudioplayer

I am writing an app that plays some simple voices and sounds using `AVAudioPlayer`. However, in order to really make the app "killer", it would need to access the users' own voice memos so that they can play back their own memos using my app (my app actually does something cool with the memos, so there is actually a point to using it! :p).

I haven't been able to find any documentation on this, nor any guides (here or out in the cloud).

Is this even possible or do I have to add a little guide asking the user to record a sound, import to iTunes, sync with device, then access it via the music library? Or perhaps another solution of recording in-app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1978698/how-to-record-the-user-voice-in-objective-c-for-iphone

Comment: It's a potential solution IF there really is no way to simply load the voice memo from the file system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right, so under the current versions of iOS, this isn't possible at all.
As mentioned, the best thing is to simply us AVAudioRecorder to record directly into the app itself.

Comment: Is this still true in mid 2023?