# iOS > How to get access to Voice Memos records programmatically?

Tags: ios, voice

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [iPhone: Access voice memos programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265215/iphone-access-voice-memos-programmatically)

I am writing app when I want user to share his Voice Memos records.
Any chance to get access to Voice Memos records programmatically?

Comment: I am also trying to access voice memos app in my app. As per my knowledge it is not possible...