# how to access voice memo in app

Tags: objective-c

I know that in your app you can access you ipod music and your camera form an app you make. I was wondering if at any possible way it was possible to use the voice memos app from your app. For example, use voice memos they have to use it as the app's background song or sound, it would be something that would give the user more customization to the way the want there screen to look or sound. Thanks, and if its not possible please let me know. If it is possible then please explain how. Thank you!

Comment: Possible Duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265215/iphone-access-voice-memos-programmatically