# Is there a way to access voice recordings made by Voice Memos?

Tags: ios

I have seen this answered before in this link [iPhone: Access voice memos programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5265215/iphone-access-voice-memos-programmatically)

and that was 4 years ago. Is it still not possible to access the recordings made by Voice Memos?

Comment: Nope, still not possible.

Comment: sigh... alright, thanks!